# Copilot in VSCode "More Actions menu... Insert into Notebook" does not format response into separate Markdown and Code cells - inconsistent setups?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions, github-copilot

I work on a team of developers using VSCode with Jupyter Notebooks for learning and building things.

Some installations of Copilot do not work correctly.  Code generated by Copilot is not correctly inserted into Jupyter NBs in all installations.

**Problem**: Copilot in VSCode "More Actions menu... Insert into Notebook" does not format response into Markdown and Code cells.  It creates one big Markdown string and inserts that into a Markdown cell in the Jupyter Notebook document.  It currently formats and embeds Python code into the Markdown object.

**What We Expect:**  Code completions are formatted correctly into Markdown and Code Cells and then the response is split and inserted into separate Markdown Cells and Code Cells.  This is so that the code can be run immediately WITHOUT manual reformatting and splitting data once it is in the Notebook.

**WHAT WE TRIED:**
We have hunted throughout the VSCode "Settings" and asked Copilot itself how to fix this and it says that it cannot be changed.  But yet it works in some older installations done last month.

We tried searching for special settings in the VSCode Settings GUI for Copilot, but could only find settings to enable different languages, but nothing to control output parsing.  Then looked into the "settings.json" file, but do not see anything for output parsers or formatters that is specifically enabled in the working installations (or disabled in the non-working installations.)

The only suggestions by Copilot to solve his problem are to uninstall and reinstall the Jupyter Notebook-related extensions.

**VERSION DOES NOT SEEM TO MATTER?**
I am using the latest version as of today [v1.851 (system setup)].   On some other installations we did the past 2 weeks, it works just fine.  Looking at different installation configuration information, they are IDENTICAL?!!?

**Question:**  Does anyone know how to fix this?  Is there some other Copilot configuration that can be changed?   IS this a bug in the current version or a configuration problem?

Comment: If you read a little bit more about LLMs, you will understand that this is by design at this moment, and GPT based products like GitHub Copilot cannot perform tasks with the accuracy you are looking for. Prompt engineering might or might not help much. You have to face it and wait for future innovation.